# UINavigationController skip push current view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have 5 view controller now, view controller 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. and I'm using UINavigationController.

I would go in by sequence, view controller 1, view controller 2, view controller 3, view controller 4

But when I click on the top left button from view controller 4, by default I will pop to 3rd view controller. I would not want that, I would want to pop to 2nd view controller. So I would want remove 3rd view controller stack when I enter 3rd view controller. So I can go to 2nd view controller from 4th view controller.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the button you could do something like this:

```
navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAtIndex(2)
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Remove the 3rd view controller then pop the 4th one, and you will get to the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

If using storyboard, you want to define an unwind segue. Add this to view controller 2:

```
@IBAction func unwindViewController2(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

Go back to storyboard and now you should see your function when linking a button's action to the exit button